# App.config / web.config editor easy config editor

Tags: deployment, configuration, editor

I have a scenario where I am asking consultants to deploy 2 applications. A console application and an IIS web service application. Both apps form part of the solution.

I haven't created an easy to use installer, but was wondering if there is an open source config editor that I can ship with my app that can read in "only certain" values and allow the consultant to change these values.

This would be much less hassle than asking the consultant to open up web.config or app.config - because the configuration is pretty complex for a non technical person, and they're overwhelmed by all the XML.

I guess as a programming question, this would be a question relating to deployment.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are the sections which you want the developers to read ?  I would refer you to this question [Can a web.config read from an external xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411184/can-a-web-config-read-from-an-external-xml-file/2411264#2411264).  You can keep part of your web/app.configs externally and read from them.

more reference:http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx