# IIS7 urlrewrite module - Rules in external xml file

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I'm using IIS7 UrlRewrite module.
I set up my rules in the web.config `<system.webServer><rewrite>` section.
I want to know if there's a way to define the rules in one external xml file instead of in web.config file.
Thanks.

Comment: Not that I know of. Why would you need that?

Comment: @Remy: Late response, but it increases readability of the web.config when you have a lot of rewrite rules. That's the reason for me anyway.

Comment: in IIS >= 7.5 remember to install URL Rewrite component from here https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Answer (score 55):

Yes, you can use the `configSource` attribute to point to an external file like you can with other web.config sections. In the web.config:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules configSource="Rewrite.config" />
</rewrite>
```

And in the rules config file:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="some rule">
        <!-- rule details here --->
    </rule>
</rules>
```

You can still even use the IIS manager to edit rules and it'll just work. One minor caveat with this approach: when you make a change and save an external file like this, it will not recycle the application like making a change to the web.config will. So if you're editing a rule and want to see it take effect, you need to manually poke the web.config by making an edit and saving it.

Another reference: [Moving IIS7 url rewrite section out of the web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333964/iis7-url-rewrite-web-config-section/4934185#4934185)

Comment: Are you sure about the application not being recycled on external changes? There is another property on config sections called [RestartOnExternalChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.restartonexternalchanges.aspx) and it defaults to true.

Comment: @atticae I believe RestartOnExternalChanges applies only to custom defined <section> elements, which rewrite rules are not. http://forums.iis.net/t/1155629.aspx I'm not sure if anything has changed since then, this thread is from 2009...

Comment: Unfortunately the IntelliSense in Rewrite.config does not work. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sample URL Rewrite providers that include one for storing those in a separate file, see:
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module

Comment: but that is for mappings. Config is used for another purpose, to set custom rules. sometimes we need to use a reg expression to all the url mappings we need then the only way is to include it in config.