# IIS Rewrite rule is stored in XML file that is deleted upon Web Publish

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

When I configure a rewrite rule in IIS, it appears in the folder in a file called web.config.

When I publish a website to the folder using MSDeploy, the file is deleted.

Is it possible to have IIS store the file somewhere else?

Comment: Maybe you can just include the generated webconfig in your web project and mark it as build action=none and copy always? It should then copy the file when you are using the msdeploy.

Comment: I suppose so but then my app’s source code is tied to IIS.

Comment: if you do not want to have web.config rules in folder, you can use https://serverfault.com/questions/567191/cant-find-iis-rewrite-rule-in-config-xml the 'Server level' option. If you are not the only citizen on IIS, use with care.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at server level when there's an app/virtual directory in between. So I will save the file to the project and count myself lucky it works at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS7 urlrewrite module - Rules in external xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767864/iis7-urlrewrite-module-rules-in-external-xml-file)