# IIS 7 URL rewrite module web.config section c#

Tags: iis-7, config

We are using IIS7 URL rewrite module with asp.net C#, all of the URLs are configured and written directly into web.config:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <!-- ... -->
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Category URL" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="somepage.aspx" ignoreCase="false"/>
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="REDIRECTION=true"
                         ignoreCase="false"/>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="categoryid=([^&amp;]*)"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/browsing/categorylanding.aspx?navcategoryid={C:1}"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
```

I need to move this to a section so that I can have seperate rules for QA, DEV and Production, what would be the "type that i would define in the section?

```xml
<configSections>
    <section name="IISURLRewriteSection" type="???"/>
</configSections>
```

Will the IIS automatically pick up these settings once moved outside from web.config to another custom config file?

Comment: Nobody seems to really answer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resorted to writing our own HTTPModule since from debugging point of view as well any issues that would arise at IIS level would have to have the Operations team involved - just following a process defined in our org :)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, imho, would be to move the configuration details into external files, which you can then swap out per-environment.

This is pretty easy to do using the method described in [Moving IIS7 url rewrite section out of the web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4934185/205245), where you would have something like this in your `Web.config` file:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite configSource="rewrite.config"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Then you can store the environment specific stuff in a separate file, `rewrite.config`, looking something like this:

```xml
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Category URL" stopProcessing="true">
            <!-- ... --->
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```