# Include directive in Apache - similar directive in IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, include

Apache's **Include** directive includes other configuration files from within the server configuration files.
e.g.,

```
Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/vhosts/*.conf
```

Does IIS7 have a similar directive to include other configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - please review any/all of the following:

[Can a web.config read from an external xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411184/can-a-web-config-read-from-an-external-xml-file)

[Moving IIS7 url rewrite section out of the web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333964/iis7-url-rewrite-web-config-section)

[IIS7 urlrewrite module - Rules in external xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767864/iis7-urlrewrite-module-rules-in-external-xml-file)