# Web.Config, external file for system.serviceModel

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config, configurationmanager

Using VS2010

I have the following in my web.config (detail removed).

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors />
    <services />
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <bindings />
    <client />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I would like to use attribute configSource the same as appSettings can use to get the detail of these elements from another config file.

I have tried to apply configSource attribute to either system.serviceModel or to each of the sub nodes.
However, I get the invalid blue wavvy line saying:

```
The 'configSource' attribute is not allowed
```

I refer to the second answer (by Tom Brothers) in this question which demonstrates what I would like.
[Can a web.config read from an external xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411184/can-a-web-config-read-from-an-external-xml-file)

**Additional**
Here is the configuration from that post. Has invalid blue wavvy lines.

```
<connectionStrings configSource="web\config\connectionStrings.config" /> 
<appSettings configSource="web\config\appSettings.config" /> 
<system.diagnostics configSource="web\config\diagnostics.config" /> 
<system.serviceModel> 
    <bindings configSource="web\config\serviceModelBindings.config" /> 
    <behaviors configSource="web\config\serviceModelBehaviors.config" /> 
    <services configSource="web\config\serviceModelServices.config" /> 
    <client configSource="web\config\serviceModelClient.config" /> 
</system.serviceModel>
```

How can I use the configSource attibute in this case?

Comment: Well, you can't apply configSource to system.serviceModel since it's a config section group.  How did you apply configSource to the underlying nodes?  Can you include what that looks like so we can see the config file that's generating the errors?

Comment: @David Hoerster: I have not been successful with that either (applying to underlying nodes). The linked article suggests it, although I cannot get it to work. I have adjusted my post to show the answer from that post.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a failing of Visual Studio. So you will have to live with permanent warnings in VS if you use this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You cannot apply `configSource=` to `<system.serviceModel>` since that is a config section **group** - not a simple config section, and the `configSource` attribute is only available on simple configuration sections.

You should however absolutely be able to apply the configSource attribute to any of the nodes inside `<system.serviceModel>`  - I do this all the time, in production systems - and it just works. Have you even really tried??

Or did you let yourself be scared off by Visual Studio... it might show you (and tell you) that `configSource="...."` is not allowed (by those wavy underlines) - but that's just a shortcoming in the Visual Studio editor - on the child nodes of `<system.serviceModel>`, it **is** allowed to have a `configSource=` attribute!

Can you show us (by editing your original question) what your e.g. `serviceModelBehaviors.config` looks like??

Also: is that file physically in the `web\config` subdirectory of your web application??

Comment: I get Visual Studio 2010 telling me that configSource is "not allowed" for my `bindings` and `client` child elements of `system.serviceModel`, too; as far as I can see, the Visual Studio 2010 editor is just wrong.

Comment: I still get this on VS2012 too

Comment: Still getting this in VS2013.

Comment: And just checked in VS2013.

Comment: Same warning in VS2015. Go microsoft!

Comment: Also getting it in VS2013 - and I'm not able to build my solution - no errors showing in the ErrorList

Comment: Same warning on VS2017 (v. 15.3.5)

Comment: Same warning on VS2019 yaay